# youtube as3 api closed captioning error

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, embedded-video, closed-captions

I am importing youtube video into my flash project but when I click the CC button I get an error image like this one

[image: closed caption error]

I have not seen anything in the [AS3 youtube api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html) for any special parameters needed to use closed captioning. Also if I copy and paste the url it calls it works fine in a web browser.

any idea what I might be missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was building for flash 9 instead of flash 10

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:  http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#cc_load_policy

```
cc_load_policy
Values: 1. Default is based on user preference. Setting to 1 will cause closed captions to be shown by default, even if the user has turned captions off.
```

Comment: I had already tried that and that is just to set if they are on when the video starts